# Insert value new cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

good morning
this script adds a cell below, it is wrong I would rather copy the value of E2 and paste it in E3, E4 etc etc every 1 hour.
Thanks to those who solve my problem.

```
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').setValue(jsonResponse.price);
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("E2:E2");
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
```

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what do you want to accomplish, and what issues have you encountered while trying to do it? Is your problem running this every 1 hour? Is it shifting the cells accordingly?

Comment: yes, this code takes the dynamic value in E2 and moves it to E3, then E3 is moved to E4, E4 to E5 etc .. every hour. I want E2 to be copied to E3, then E2 to E4 E2 to E5 etc. It must not add cells, but copy new E2 every hour into a cell below like E3, E4; E5 etc.
I hope I have been understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Time-driven trigger:

The script you shared will effectively shift the cells in column E down, with `E3` containing the newest value (`E2` will be blank). You want this function to run automatically each hour. For this, you need to install a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). The trigger needed in this case would be [everyHours(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyHours(Integer)). You can install either manually, by following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, by running the following function once:

```js
function createHourTrigger() {
  var triggeredFunction = "shiftAndSet"; // Triggered function name, change accordingly
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggeredFunction) 
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(1)
    .create();
}
```

#### Note:

Your script has a certain amount of repetition and could be reduced to this (the code to retrieve `jsonResponse` is obviously missing):

```js
function shiftAndSet() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E2");
  range.setValue(jsonResponse.price);
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```

Also, if you want `E2` and not `E3` to have the newest value at the end of each execution, you could change the order of actions, like this:

```js
function shiftAndSet() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E2");
  range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  range.setValue(jsonResponse.price);
}
```

Comment: @Mirko Glad it worked. Also, would you consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , if it was helpful?  This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.